# Where is the ‘poll’ function of ordinary disk files implemented in the Linux source code?

Tags: c++, c, linux, file, linux-kernel

The disk file of Linux is represented in the kernel using a ‘file’ structure. There is a ‘file_operations’ in the file structure, which is an array of pointers, and one of them is a ‘poll’ function pointer. as follows:

```
struct file {
...
Const struct file_operations * f_op;
...
}

struct file_operations {
...
Ssize_t (* read) (struct file *, char __user *, size_t, loff_t *);
...
Ssize_t (* write) (struct file *, const char __user *, size_t, loff_t *);
...
Unsigned int (* poll) (struct file *, struct poll_table_struct *);
...
}
```

I also know that the reading and writing of disk files will go through a layer of virtual file system (VFS).

What I want to ask is:

Does the virtual file system implement the ‘poll’ function?

Where is the ‘poll’ function of ordinary disk files implemented in the Linux source code?

Comment: "Does the virtual file system implement the ‘poll’ function?" - No, it doesn't. "Where is the ‘poll’ function of ordinary disk files implemented in the Linux source code?" - Just grep for the word "poll" in the filesystem drivers.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Looking in the '/fs' directory, or in the '/drivers' directory?

Comment: Filesystem drivers are located under `fs/` subdirectory. E.g., `fs/ext4/` contains the driver for ext4 filesystem.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I have found many implementations of the poll method, I don't know which one? http://androidxref.com/kernel_3.0/search?q=.poll&defs=&refs=&path=&hist=&project=fs

Answer (score 1):

> Where is the ‘poll’ function of ordinary disk files implemented in the Linux source code?

`poll` function is **not implemented** for "**ordinary**" files.

For such files `read` and `write` operations are **never block**, so polling them will always return immediately.

Polling is useful for *special* files, like pipes or sockets. Only those files have `poll` function implemented.

Comment: thinks.I read or write some new bytes from a normal file, so what does the poll function return immediately? The poll function does not block itself. The blocking is done by the process scheduling function. Reading or writing some new bytes should unblock it?

Comment: By "polling" the file I mean calling a *system call* like `select`/`poll`/`epoll` for that file. These system calls are implemented by VFS, so they can be used for every file. By **default**, all files are treated as **available for read and write without blocking**. So would you poll the regular("ordinary") file for `POLLIN` event, the polling would return immediately and report that the file is ready for `POLLIN` event. The `poll` is a *file operation*, which should be implemented for files which need *non-default* polling behavior. Regular ("ordinary") files don't implement this function.

Comment: Regular ("ordinary") files don't implement this function，so  the poll function return 0 by Regular ("ordinary") files？

Comment: The `poll` function in the driver should return the mask of operations, already available for the file. So description "By **default**, all files are treated as available for read and write without blocking" means, that "default implementation" of `poll` returns `POLLIN | POLLOUT`. (That is, when `poll` is not set for the file, then instead of calling this function `POLLIN | POLLOUT` is used in futher VFS computations.)